# Как в 1С программно выбрать Инв. № с конкретным номером организации, в инвентаризации ОС?

Tags: 1с

Когда переходим в конкретную организацию, то получаем конкретный список инвентаризаций:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для получения `Инв. №` написал такой код:

```
&НаСервере
Процедура ИнвентарьОсновныхСредств()

ЗапросН = Новый запрос;
    ЗапросН.Текст = 
    "ВЫБРАТЬ
    |    ПервоначальныеСведенияОСБухгалтерскийУчетСрезПоследних.ИнвентарныйНомер
    |ИЗ
    |    РегистрСведений.ПервоначальныеСведенияОСБухгалтерскийУчет.СрезПоследних КАК ПервоначальныеСведенияОСБухгалтерскийУчетСрезПоследних";
    
    
РезультатЗапросаН = ЗапросН.Выполнить();
ВыборкаДокументовН = РезультатЗапросаН.Выбрать();

Пока ВыборкаДокументовН.Следующий() Цикл
    
ДокН = ВыборкаДокументовН.ИнвентарныйНомер;    

Сообщить(ДокН);

КонецЦикла;
    
КонецПроцедуры


&НаКлиенте
Процедура Команда1(Команда)

ИнвентарьОсновныхСредств();    
    
КонецПроцедуры
```

Здесь мы получаем все `Инв. №`.

Как сделать так, чтобы выбрать по номеру организации (`5563`) + по номеру инвентаризации (`1158`)?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду как наложить отбор?!

Comment: @Sagittarius, да. Чтобы отбирать по номеру организации (который в основной вкладке Инвентаризации ОС) и по номеру инвентаризации (после того как открываем вкладку из списка Инвентаризация ОС)

Comment: для этого надо структуру данных знать. Покажите картинку метаданных регистра. А вообще, для наложения условия надо использовать секцию "ГДЕ" запроса.
[Тут](https://programmist1s.ru/zaprosyi-1s-ot-a-do-ya/#i-5) можно посмотреть примеры.

Comment: @Sagittarius Вот картинка регистра: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1wcn.png

Comment: Все равно мне так тяжело всю структуру охватить. Надо "на живую" смотреть. Судя по всему, в напрямую отборы сделать по регистру не получится. Не вижу в нем данных о документе.

Comment: Скачайте себе консоль запросов, это позволит выполнять отладку запроса в режиме предприятия. Второе, используйте ссылки на объекты в условиях а не номера. У документа может быть нумерация в пределах года. То есть ежегодно будет создаваться документ с номером "5"
Также проверьте, что выступает регистратором для регистра. Это документ который формирует движения. Если в перечне присутствует "ИнвениаризацияОС", то вот ваш второй параметр для отбора.

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо добавить отбор по заданным параметрам. Также, когда выполняете "срез последних", лучше указывать дату, на которую выполняется срез. Если у регистра регистратором выступает документ "ИнвентаризацияОС", то подойдет следующий код под ваши условия:

```
ВЫБРАТЬ
|    ПервоначальныеСведенияОСБухгалтерскийУчетСрезПоследних.ИнвентарныйНомер
|ИЗ
|    РегистрСведений.ПервоначальныеСведенияОСБухгалтерскийУчет.СрезПоследних КАК ПервоначальныеСведенияОСБухгалтерскийУчетСрезПоследних
|ГДЕ
|    ПервоначальныеСведенияОСБухгалтерскийУчетСрезПоследних.Организация.Код = &Код
|    ПервоначальныеСведенияОСБухгалтерскийУчетСрезПоследних.Регистратор.Номер = &Номер
```

Но использование в запросах номеров и кодов "bed practice", кроме отдельных специфичных случаев. Лучше использовать ссылки на объекты, либо сужать выборку дополнительными условиями.